# Derived Object at same Location as Base Object

Tags: c++, pointers, derived

I have the problem, that I have a pointer to a base class object "Element" in a class "List". In certain situations I need Element to be a more specialized type "Transition". Transition is derived from Element. But when I make a Transition object from the pointer to the Element object the pointer now is decoupled from my matrix class List.

In my research so far, I had read though, that this is the way to create a derived object.
But this is not what I had in mind... I want the derived object to be at the same location as the base class pointer (pointer to Element class, "last").
How would I need to do that?

Example code:

```
#include <iostream>


class Element{

    public:

        Element(){
            member = 0;
        }

        virtual void set_member(int i){}

        void print_member(){
        std::cout << member << std::endl;
    }

    protected:
        int member;

};


class Transition: public Element{

    public:
        void set_member(int i){
            member = i;
        }

};


class List{

    public:

    List(){
        last = new Element;
    }

    Element*    get_last(){
            return last;
        }

    void print(){
        last->print_member();
    }

    private:
        Element* last;

};

int main(){

    List list;
    Element* last = list.get_last();
    last = new Transition; // creates completely new entity.
                           // I wanted to make a derived object
                           // from Element at the same location
                           // as the Elememt object though
    last->set_member(1);
    last->print_member(); // returns newly assigned value
    list.print(); // returns default value of Element type
                  // but I wanted itto return newly assigned value

}
```

Comment: Please be aware that you code as written has at least two memory leaks. It might be worth describing what you are actually trying to do, in that way you might find an answer that solves your real problem (i.e. the way you have structured the solution).

Comment: Well, what I actually want to do it access the last element of a list via the last-pointer that is an attribute of my list class. Then I want to change an attribute of the last list element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Element* last = list.get_last();
last = new Transition;
```

Now the local variable `last` has nothing to do with member variable `last` in class `List`, so the behaviour on local variable won't influence the member variable `last`. You might need a settor method to set it back. Such as:

```
class List {
public:
    void set_last(Element* e) {
        last = e;
    }

    // ...
};
```

And then in `main`:

```
int main() {
    List list;
    Element* last = new Transition; // creates completely new entity.
    last->set_member(1);
    list.set_last(last);            // set it back to List
    list.print();
}
```

**[EDIT]**
BTW: You use a raw pointer in your class `List`, you need to pay attention to the management of it. For example, you should `delete` it in the destructor, and before set a new pointer to it, `delete` the old pointer, and so on. And in general, to adopt RAII idiom by using a smart pointer (such as `std::unique_ptr`) is a better solution.

Comment: I see, thanks.
I was so fixated on how I thought it would work, that I completely tunnel-visioned out that obvious solution.

Answer (score 2):

> I want the derived object to be at the same location as the base class pointer (pointer to Element class, "last"). How would I need to do that?

Let me understand what you are trying to do.

You have:

```
Element* last = list.get_last();
```

At this point, `last` points to a valid object that is either `Element` or a sub-type of `Element`.

Now you want to create a `Transition` object and want that object's address to be the same as the address of the object `last` points to?

Short answer: **DON'T DO IT**

Long answer:

Yes, you can do something like that using the [placement `new` operator](http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#placement-new).

However, you must know everything about the memory location before you can use it.

1. You must know that there is enough memory at that location to hold a `Transition` object.
2. The life of the object that lived there must be terminated by calling its destructor.
3. No other part of the program tries to access that memory location using the previous object type.
4. You can't call `delete` on the pointer. `delete` must be called on the same pointer type that was returned by `new`. Otherwise, you will be in undefined behavior territory.
5. If the memory was allocated using `new []` operator, it must be deallocated using the `delete []` operator. If the memory was allocated using  the plain `new` operator, it must be deallocated using the plain `delete` operator.

There might be more pitfalls that I don't necessarily recall.

Comment: Thank you, then this approach is clearly beyond my current level of understanding.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as others are saying.. I think this needs to be re-factored a bit.

But given the question you asked, realize that this:

```
Element*    get_last(){
        return last;
    }
```

is returning a pointer to last (the thing you new'd), but you aren't looking to change last, you are looking to change the pointer to last. This could be done like this:

```
Element**    get_last(){
        return &last;
    }
```

This would return the pointer to the pointer to element. Then you could then set that pointer to a new object, but realize that if you do that you have just leaked the memory of the element you originally newed. Everything you new *must* be deleted (even if you go with songyuanyao's comment above.. make sure you delete the old element in the set_last and in your list destructor). So you would end up with:

```
Element ** last = list.get_last();
delete(*last); // Removes the old entity from memory.
*last = new Transition; // creates completely new entity.
```

I can think of no circumstance I would write this though.. it really does seem to me like you need some re-factoring.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I was approaching my issue in an over-complicated manner.

My solution is now this:

```
#include <iostream>


class Element{

    public:

        Element(){
            member = 0;
            successor = 0;
        }

        virtual void set_member(int i){}

        virtual void set_successor(int successor){}

        void print(){
        std::cout << member << std::endl;
        std::cout << successor << std::endl;
    }

    protected:
        int member;
        int successor;

};


class Transition: public Element{

    public:
        void set_member(int i){
            member = i;
        }

        void set_successor(int i){
            successor = i;
        }

};


class List{

    public:

    List(){
        last = new Transition;
    }

    Element*    get_last(){
            return last;
    }

    void set_last(Element* new_last){
        last = new_last;
    }

    void print(){
        last->print();
    }

    private:
        Element* last;

};

int main(){

    List list;
    (list.get_last())->set_member(6);
    (list.get_last())->set_successor(8);
    list.print();

}
```